# Multiline .format() method with group of variables in python 3

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, format, multiline

This works as is but the .format could be summarised

my question is how can I use the .format method more efficiently. I tried .format(switch) and .format([switch]) but theye error out.

what would be the correct syntax to avoid writing all the variables out again

syntax below..

```
switch = [SW_1, Int_1, Vlan_num, Des]  #group of input variables
config1 = """
interface GigabitEthernet {1}
description {3}
switchport
switchport access vlan {2}
""".format(SW_1, Int_1, Vlan_num, Des)

print(config1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
switch = [SW_1, Int_1, Vlan_num, Des] #group of input variables
config1 = """
interface GigabitEthernet {1}
description {3}
switchport
switchport access vlan {2}
""".format(*switch)
```

Read more about using the single star in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists.  If you want to research more, "unpacking arguments" is the key phrase you need.